# ¿Cómo muestro un archivo PDF apenas se inicia la aplicación en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, pdf, visual-studio-2017

Para poder mostrar el archivo PDF estoy usando la librería de **Adobe PDF Reader - (axAcroPDFLib)**.
Tengo un archivo PDF con el nombre(**PDF1**) que está incrustado en el **Recurso** del Proyecto **(Carpeta Resources)** y quiero mostrar apenas **mi aplicación se inicie**, **intenté** utilizar el siguiente código en el evento **Load** par que apenas se inicie mi aplicación se muestre mi PDF:

```
        private void Prueba_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            axAcroPDF1.src = Properties.Resources.PDF1;
        }
```

> - **axAcroPDF1:** Es el nombre del control para poder visualizar el PDF.

[image: Form PDF]

> - **PDF1:** Es el archivo que quiero que se muestre apenas se inicie la aplicación.
> - **Properties.Resources:** Ubicación del archivo PDF;

pero me aparece el mesaje de: **No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'byte[]' en 'string'.**
¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi PDF se muestre apenas se inicie mi aplicación?.

Comment: El error es claro. `src` tiene que ser la ruta del archivo pdf, no el pdf en si mismo. Me temo que tendrás que volcar tu pdf a una carpeta temporal y pasarle esa ruta al control.

Comment: @Pikoh entonces tienes que ser algo similar a esto: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders

Comment: Te he añadido una respuesta de como lo haría yo. Mira si te sirve.

Comment: En StackOverflow se espera la cortesía de votar por las respuestas que han resultado útiles y marcar una como respuesta aceptada. Ese simple gesto beneficia a toda la comunidad :)

Answer (score 1):

la propiedad `src` en el control `AxAcroPDF` debe hacer referencia a una ruta dentro de tu disco. Lo que debes hacer es volcar el archivo en una carpeta temporal y pasarle la ruta al control, algo asi:

```
string temporal = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), "PDFtemporal.pdf");
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(temporal, Properties.Resources.PDF1);
AxAcroPDF1.src = temporal;
```

Comment: Me sale un error en WriteAllBytes, me aparece el siguiente mensaje: Ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'WriteAllBytes' toma 3 argumentos.

Comment: @JhonH. si perdona fallo mio. Quita el ultimo parámetro, he editado la respuesta

Comment: eh intentado pero cuando inicio mi aplicación no se muestra mi PDF, intenté llamar mediante un botón pero tampoco me mostró el PDF.

Comment: @JhonH. prueba a escribir el archivo con streams como te propongo en mi respuesta.